# Getting a security error when i set document.domain

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I am trying to bypass the same-origin policy of a domain to click on the contents of a cross domain frame.

The code didn't work because the same origin policy is enforced.

So,i decided to use document.domain to set the subdomain and the parent page to the same address.

Then i tried setting the document.domain but i keep getting a security error.

I used the document.domain syntax,but when i run the code i get a security error.

```
    document.domain;
//returns www.example.com
  document.domain = "example.com"
```

I keep getting "Security Error: The operation is insecure".

Comment: You can’t set it to a domain that isn’t a suffix of your current one, if that’s what you’re trying to do. Also, generally, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Ry- i am trying to bypass the same-origin policy to click on the contents of an iframe.

Comment: @tiguchi,it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @AlonEitan,it has been edited.

Comment: You can't bypass the same-origin policy.

Comment: @Barmar,i meant how to escape the same origin policy.

Comment: You can't escape the same-origin policy, that would be a huge security problem.

Comment: E.g. if you have an iframe where the user logs into a web site, it would allow the containing page to get the user's password.

Comment: I understand but there are ways to escape it like i read.document.domain is one of them postmessage() also there..

Comment: There are tools to communicate across origins, when both sides use those tools (i.e. cooperate). Do you control the inside of the iframe as well?

Comment: @Ry- The inside of the frame is restricted  due to cross origin issues...so i need to handle the same origin policy safely then trigger a click on the elements i want to click.

Comment: Does the inside of the frame belong to you, though? If it doesn’t, obviously you can’t trigger clicks on some unrelated website.

Comment: @Ry-the domain wants me to click on the elements of the frame manually but i want to use code to do the clicking.both the domain and the frame does not belong to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have a choice than to switch my browser to google chrome and i disabled the same origin policy through answers from [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) and voila.